# jquery - click, append, load, slideDown not displaying as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement, what I thought would be a simple `click`, `load`, `slideDown` scenario. But I can't get the slideDown part to display.

I have the following two buttons:

```
<div>
    <fieldset id="btn">
        <input class="databasebtn" type="submit" name="nameDatabaseBtn" id="db1" data-id=1" VALUE="DB1"/></br>
        <input class="databasebtn" type="submit" name="nameDatabaseBtn" id="db2" data-id="2" VALUE="DB2"/></br>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I then have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('.databasebtn').on('click',function()
            {
                $(this).append("<div id='btnlist'></div>");
                $('#btnlist').slideDown("200",function()
                    {
                        $('#btnlist').load("test78b.php");
                    }); 
            })
    });
```

The idea being that I click the button, I append the `#btnlist` div to the button, and fill the new div with the contents of test78b.php, which should generate a list of checkboxes.

It all works fine, except that I can't see the checkboxes. If I look at the code in the background it is all there, it just wont show up.

If I include 'test78b.php' separately it displays as expected.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: How about making fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not append div to a button, you can append div to a parent in this case fildset with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
        $('.databasebtn').on('click',function(){
                $(this).parent().append("<div id='btnlist'></div>");
                $('#btnlist').slideDown('slow',function(){
                        $('#btnlist').load("your page");
                    })
           })  
  });
 </script>
```

or you can use insertBefore to append div before butoon clicked with this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
        $('.databasebtn').on('click',function(){
               $("<div id='btnlist'></div>").insertBefore($(this))
                $('#btnlist').slideDown('slow',function(){
                        $('#btnlist').load("your page");
                    })
           })  
  });
 </script>
```

or append div to the body tag with this other code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()  {
        $('.databasebtn').on('click',function(){
               $("<div id='btnlist'></div>").appendTo('body')
                $('#btnlist').slideDown('slow',function(){
                        $('#btnlist').load("your page");
                    })
           })  
  });
 </script>
```

and then, for a correct html code,you shouldn't have multiple items on the same page with the same id. 
The div added via script should not have id btnlist but class="btnlist"

Comment: cheers, that makes sense now. So if I add another tag either side of each button (e.g. <span><input . . . .), I can then apply it to the <span> as the parent, and my checkboxes appear below the button.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/TWQbD/4/

```
$('.databasebtn').on('click',function() {
        $(this).next('.databasetext').append("<div class='btnlist'>test78b.php</div>");
        $(this).next('.databasetext').find('.btnlist').last().slideDown("1000"); 
});
```